# Bind query resolution time in munin

Tags: munin

Is it possible to graph the query resolution time of bind9 in munin?

I know there is a way to graph it in a unbound server, is it already done in bind? If not how do I start writing a munin plugin for that? I'm getting stats from `http://127.0.0.1:8053/` in the bind9 server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that "query time" is a function of BIND.  About the only time that I see that value (with individual lookups) is when using dig.  If you're willing to use that, the following might be a good starting point:

```
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
  config)
    cat <<'EOM'
graph_title Red Hat Query Time
graph_vlabel time
time.label msec
EOM
    exit 0;;
esac

echo -n "time.value "
dig www.redhat.com|grep Query|cut -d':' -f2|cut -d\  -f2
```

Note that there's two spaces after the "-d\" in the second cut statement.  If you save the above as "querytime" and run it at the command line, output should look something like:

```
root@pi1:~# ./querytime
time.value 189

root@pi1:~# ./querytime config
graph_title Red Hat Query Time
graph_vlabel time
time.label msec
```

I'm not sure of the value in tracking the above though.  The response time can be affected: if the query is an initial lookup, if the answer is cached locally, depending on server load, depending on intervening network congestion, etc.

Note: the above may be a bit buggy as I've written it on the fly, but it should give you a good starting point.  That it returned the above output is a good sign.

In any case, recommend reading the following before you write your own: http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/HowToWritePlugins